# jQuery $this not working

Tags: jquery

I have this ajax call

```
  $('#viewproject').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('val'));
    $.ajax({
       type:'PATCH', 
       url: "../home/"+$(this).data('val'), 
       data: $.param({ id: 1})
    });
  });
```

That im calling in rails

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <li>
      <figure>
         <img src="<%= project.imageurl %>">
         <figcaption>
         <h3><%= project.title %></h3>
         <i class="icon-eye-open"><%= project.count %> Views</i>
         <a id="viewproject" data-val="<%= project.id %>" target="_blank" href="<%= project.imagelink %>">Take a look</a>
      </figcaption>
      </figure>
   </li>
 <% end %>
```

But it only works for the first button with the id of viewproject. Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Multiple HTML elements should not have the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID selector `#viewproject` will only ever return a single element because *there should only every be one element with the id `viewproject`*

That's why you are only attaching a handler to the first `<a>` tag.

Use a class instead.

So something like:

```
<a class="viewproject" data-val="<%= project.id %>" target="_blank" href="<%= project.imagelink %>">Take a look</a>
```

and then:

```
$('.viewproject').click(function() { //...
```

For more background, read the docs on the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), especially note this part (emphasis mine):

> Selects a **single** element with the given id attribute.

It actually translates to a `document.getElementById` which, as the name suggests, also only ever returns a single element.

Answer (score 1):

IDs on HTML elements are unique identifiers.

Use a class on your element instead:

```
<a class="viewproject" data-val="<%= project.id %>" target="_blank" href="<%= project.imagelink %>">Take a look</a>
```

...and update your jQuery selector to reflect that change:

`$('.viewproject')`

CSS-Tricks has an excellent article about id vs. classes: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use id's for multiple elements in html.
Changing "id="example"" to "class="example"" will fix your problem.
BR

Answer (score 0):

Ids must be unique of elements,In Id case as there are multiple elements with same id, it will always target only the first element it will find in DOM and will leave the rest.

So instead of id use class as you are iterating to generate multiple blocks of html:

```
<a class="viewproject" data-val="<%= project.id %>" target="_blank" href="<%= project.imagelink %>">Take a look</a>
```

and write event on class selector:

```
$('.viewproject').click(function() {
........
........
```